# String Sorting in SQL

Tags: sql-server

Hey Everyone I have this SQL query and I'm getting better with my queries, but I'm still not that good at parsing data to make it look how you want.

```
SELECT r.queueName, COUNT(*) as qty FROM LeaseComplete.dbo.QueueEntries q
    INNER JOIN LeaseComplete.dbo.Queues r
        ON r.queueID = q.queueentryQueueID
    LEFT JOIN LeaseComplete.dbo.QueueActions a 
        ON a.queueactQueueEntryID = q.queueentryID
        AND a.queueactCreationDate >(CONVERT(datetime, GETDATE()) -1)
    WHERE q.queueentryAddDate > (CONVERT(datetime, GETDATE()) -1) 
    AND q.queueentryTaskTypeCode = 'Collection'
    AND q.queueentryStatus != 'Closed'
    AND r.queueTypeCode = 'Collection'
    AND r.queueTypeCode = 'Mileage'
    AND r.queueTypeCode = 'Insurance'
    AND r.queueName NOT LIKE '%referral%'
    OR r.queueName LIKE '%Awhite%'
    OR r.queueName LIKE '%Dsmith%'
    OR r.queueName LIKE '%Kmartin%'
    OR r.queueName LIKE '%Mgonzalez%'
    OR r.queueName LIKE '%Ckponton%'
    OR r.queueName LIKE '%WTamayo%'
    OR r.queueName LIKE '%mbare%'
    OR r.queueName LIKE '%dlittle%'

    GROUP BY r.queueName
```

So what I have is the above query and it is supposed to pull any data with the first initial, last name of the `queueName` col and if it contains Mileage, Insurance, and Collection as Well. So I get the data set below.

```
+--------------------------------+-----+
|           queueName            | qty |
+--------------------------------+-----+
| Collection AWhite Delinquent   | 494 |
| Collection AWhite Followup     |  10 |
| Collection AWhite Legal        |   9 |
| Collection CKponton Delinquent | 790 |
| Collection CKponton Followup   |  38 |
| Collection CKponton Mileage    |   2 |
| Collection DLittle Delinquent  | 114 |
| Collection DLittle Legal       |  28 |
| Collection DSmith Delinquent   | 486 |
| Collection DSmith Followup     |  21 |
| Collection DSmith Legal        |  56 |
| Collection KMartin Delinquent  |  97 |
| Collection KMartin Followup    |   3 |
| Collection MBare Delinquent    | 773 |
| Collection MBare Followup      |  22 |
| Collection MBare Legal         |   1 |
| Collection MBare Mileage       |  44 |
| Collection MGonzalez Delinquen | 739 |
| Collection MGonzalez Followup  |  31 |
| Collection Referral DSmith     | 107 |
| Collection WTamayo Delinquent  | 682 |
| Collection WTamayo Followup    |  21 |
| Collection WTamayo Mileage     |   1 |
| Insurance Collection AWhite    |  44 |
| Insurance Collection CKponton  |  59 |
| Insurance Collection DLittle   |  17 |
| Insurance Collection DSmith    |  46 |
| Insurance Collection KMartin   |   2 |
| Insurance Collection MBare     |  40 |
| Insurance Collection MGonzalez |  35 |
| Insurance Collection WTamayo   |  50 |
| Insurance Monitor AWhite       |   2 |
| Insurance Monitor CKponton     |   2 |
| Insurance Monitor MBare        |   1 |
| Insurance Monitor MGonzalez    |   3 |
| Insurance Monitor WTamayo      |   2 |
+--------------------------------+-----+
```

As you can see it still pulls the 'Referral' in the columns at least once, which isn't something that I was wanting. I'm also trying to figure out how to make it so it won't show the `Insurance Monitor` Column either. How do I get these string names to take precedence over each other in a proper manner. Sorry if my grammar is terrible, I'm still waking up for the day.

Comment: Unrelated to the way you are getting the results, your `WHERE` conditions are messed up: `AND r.queueTypeCode = 'Collection' AND AND r.queueTypeCode = 'Mileage'`?, this isn't possible (you might want to think in using `IN`). Also, you are later adding `OR` conditions without parentheses (which is why you actually get results, but they are almost certainly not the results you want)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is toast: You're mixing `AND` and `OR` conditions without any `()` to enforce the parse/execution ordder, and you've got impossible conditions:

```
AND r.queueTypeCode = 'Collection'
AND r.queueTypeCode = 'Mileage'
```

It is not possible for a single field/value to have MULTIPLE different values at the same time. You're basically saying "This field must be a banana and a submarine simultaneously".

As well: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html   Note that `AND` has a HIGHER precedence than `OR`.

Comment: This is actually a very good explanation. I get operator-precedence , to an extent at least I'll have to say, so how to I go about fixing this up so that I can make it be a "banana then a submarine"

Comment: if you want the collection/mileage/insurance records, then it'd have to be an `OR`, which can be simplified down to `r.queueTypeCode IN ('Collection', 'Mileage', 'Insurance')`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you want somethig like

```
SELECT r.queueName, COUNT(*) as qty FROM LeaseComplete.dbo.QueueEntries q
    INNER JOIN LeaseComplete.dbo.Queues r
        ON r.queueID = q.queueentryQueueID
    LEFT JOIN LeaseComplete.dbo.QueueActions a 
        ON a.queueactQueueEntryID = q.queueentryID
        AND a.queueactCreationDate >(CONVERT(datetime, GETDATE()) -1)
    WHERE (q.queueentryAddDate > (CONVERT(datetime, GETDATE()) -1) 
    AND q.queueentryTaskTypeCode = 'Collection'
    AND q.queueentryStatus != 'Closed'
    AND r.queueTypeCode IN ('Collection', 'Mileage', 'Insurance')
    AND r.queueName NOT LIKE '%referral%')
    AND( r.queueName LIKE '%Awhite%'
    OR r.queueName LIKE '%Dsmith%'
    OR r.queueName LIKE '%Kmartin%'
    OR r.queueName LIKE '%Mgonzalez%'
    OR r.queueName LIKE '%Ckponton%'
    OR r.queueName LIKE '%WTamayo%'
    OR r.queueName LIKE '%mbare%'
    OR r.queueName LIKE '%dlittle%')

    GROUP BY r.queueName
    ORDER BY r.queueName
```

Comment: This doesn't pull the `Insurance Collection Queue` I'm currently experimenting to figure this out

Comment: u can change `OR r.queueName LIKE '%dlittle%')` to
`OR r.queueName LIKE '%dlittle%'
OR r.queueName LIKE '%Collection%')`